# Why do I have different array dimensions only when not using todays date?

Tags: python

I am trying to get stock data for a company and predict stock prices in the future. I know this isn't accurate, but I am using it as a learning tool. When using today's date as the end date and the predicted date as a date in the future my code appears to work. However, when using a past date and predicting the future this produces an error:

"ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (220,) and (221,)"

I want to do this as then I would be able to compare predictions to actual prices.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as web
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

stock_name = 'BP.L'

prices = web.DataReader(stock_name, 'yahoo', start = '2019-01-01', end = '2019-11-05').reset_index(drop = False)[['Date', 'Adj Close']]


#plt.plot(prices['Date'], prices['Adj Close'])
#plt.xlabel('Days')
#plt.ylabel('Stock Prices')
#plt.show()


# Parameter Definitions

# So    :   initial stock price
# dt    :   time increment -> a day in our case
# T     :   length of the prediction time horizon(how many time points to predict, same unit with dt(days))
# N     :   number of time points in the prediction time horizon -> T/dt
# t     :   array for time points in the prediction time horizon [1, 2, 3, .. , N]
# mu    :   mean of historical daily returns
# sigma :   standard deviation of historical daily returns
# b     :   array for brownian increments
# W     :   array for brownian path

start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2019-01-01'
pred_end_date = '2019-11-05'

# We get daily closing stock prices
S_eon = web.DataReader(stock_name, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date).reset_index(drop = False)[['Date', 'Adj Close']]

So = S_eon.loc[S_eon.shape[0] -1, "Adj Close"]

dt = 1

n_of_wkdays = pd.date_range(start = pd.to_datetime(end_date, 
              format = "%Y-%m-%d") + pd.Timedelta('1 days'), 
              end = pd.to_datetime(pred_end_date, 
              format = "%Y-%m-%d")).to_series(
              ).map(lambda x: 
              1 if x.isoweekday() in range(1,6) else 0).sum()
T = n_of_wkdays

N = T / dt

t = np.arange(1, int(N) + 1)

returns = (S_eon.loc[1:, 'Adj Close'] - \
          S_eon.shift(1).loc[1:, 'Adj Close']) / \
          S_eon.shift(1).loc[1:, 'Adj Close']

mu = np.mean(returns)

sigma = np.std(returns)


scen_size = 10000
b = {str(scen): np.random.normal(0, 1, int(N)) for scen in range(1, scen_size + 1)}

W = {str(scen): b[str(scen)].cumsum() for scen in range(1, scen_size + 1)}

drift = (mu - 0.5 * sigma**2) * t
diffusion = {str(scen): sigma * W[str(scen)] for scen in range(1, scen_size + 1)}

S = np.array([So * np.exp(drift + diffusion[str(scen)]) for scen in range(1, scen_size + 1)]) 
S = np.hstack((np.array([[So] for scen in range(scen_size)]), S))
S_avg = np.mean(S)
print(S_avg)

#Plotting 
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
for i in range(scen_size):
    plt.title("Daily Volatility: " + str(sigma))
    plt.plot(pd.date_range(start = S_eon["Date"].max(), 
                end = pred_end_date, freq = 'D').map(lambda x:
                x if x.isoweekday() in range(1, 6) else np.nan).dropna(), S[i, :])
    plt.ylabel('Stock Prices, €')
    plt.xlabel('Prediction Days')
plt.show()
```

The error shows:

"File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 270, in _xy_from_xy
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))"

Comment: At which line is the error? Please answer as an edit to the question, and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add one day more to the prediction end date?

```py
pred_end_date = '2019-11-06'
```

Your error is just a shape mismatch and your date series miss only one value

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday):

> date.isoweekday()
>
> Return the day of the week as an integer, where
> Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7. For example, date(2002, 12,
> 4).isoweekday() == 3, a Wednesday. See also weekday(), isocalendar().

This returns a number between 1 and 7, and you're checking the range 1 to 6, converting other values to `na`. Then you `dropna` them, so you lose a value.

Change it to `x if x.isoweekday() in range(1, 7)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following and it now works:

```
"x if x.isoweekday() in range(1, 6) else np.nan).dropna(), S[i, :])"
```

to:

```
"x if x.isoweekday() in range(1, 6) else np.nan).dropna(), S[i, :-1])"
```